# Generating BiBTeX Source from LuaLaTeX

Tags: bibtex, luatex, luacode

I am wondering if there's a way to generate the BibTeX entries directly from the LuaLaTeX source of the document being compiled. Given a particular filing system, the LuaTeX source might have all the information that one would want:

1. Type of Document  (Article, Report, Book)
2. Author /Title
3. Custom Variable Names like Version, Department etc

If these variables are accessible from the lua part of the code, and if the `\directlua` allows one to write files, then it might be possible to generate a `.bib` file as a part of compiling the document.

I am wondering if my line of inquiry is valid and if someone has already attempted something similar to what I have described above.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the LuaLaTeX of the document".

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to generate a BiBTeX entry to refer to the document currently being compiled from other documents? There is no need to use Lua for that, you can write out that information purely from TeX code. How easily it is available will depend a lot on the used document class.

Comment: Yes. You understood my question correctly. I tried to search if someone had already done it, but I couldn't find anything. And my knowledge of TeX is not thorough enough to know how it could be done by itself. I'll try to search what methods can be used. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lua is definitely not required. My template for my own working documents start with

```
%% Metadata
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,noheader]{\jobname.meta-bib}
@article
author = {test, test},
title = {title},
keywords = {GR},
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{...
```

This allows you to put whatever bibliographic data you want within the `filecontents` environment and have it saved to a `.meta-bib` file, which you can then vacuum up using a shell-script. (In my case the data I include is incomplete [missing some braces and the identifying key] because my vacuuming shell-script generates those automatically, but you can instead do everything by hand.)

The solution above is probably the most flexible, as it does not require knowledge / assumptions about individual document classes. An alternative method is to write a package (`.sty`) file that automate this process; this would require

- Redefining `\title` to write the long title to the bib file; care has to be taken for document classes that allow optional arguments for `\title`.
- Redefining `\author` to write the author info into the bib file; this can be extremely difficult as some document classes expect the author address as part of the `\author` command, and some document classes do not. And some document classes list individual authors with multiple `\author` calls, and some document classes use `\author{Author1 \and Author2 \and Author3}`.

  My inability to fully automate this for all the common document classes I use is why I reverted to just using `filecontents` to write out the data by hand.
- In any case, if your paper ends up published, there's no way that you can find the publication information (journal, volume, date) purely based on the source alone, *unless* you hard code it into the TeX file somehow. In this case, you get back to something that is almost the same as the `filecontents` solution mentioned above but with a lot less flexibility.

---

By request, the "vacuum script" (nothing fancy at all, except it also generates time stamps using Git commit info)

```
#!/bin/bash

BIBFILE="entries.bib"

echo '% Automatically generated entries database' > $BIBFILE
echo -n '% Updated: ' >> $BIBFILE
date >> $BIBFILE

for texfile in `git ls-tree master --name-only *tex`
do
        bname=`basename -s .tex $texfile`
        if [ ${bname}.meta-bib -ot $texfile ]
        then
                echo "${texfile} out of date, skipping."
        else
                moddate=`git log -n 1 --date="format:%F %R" --format="format:%cd" ${texfile}`
                modcommit=`git log -n 1 --format="format:%h" ${texfile}`
                origdate=`git log  --date="format:%F" --format="format:%cd" --diff-filter=A ${texfile}`
                head -n 1 ${bname}.meta-bib >> $BIBFILE
                echo "{ $bname," >> $BIBFILE
                tail -n +2 ${bname}.meta-bib >> $BIBFILE
                echo "lastdate = {${moddate}}," >> $BIBFILE
                echo "lastcommit = {${modcommit}}," >> $BIBFILE
                echo "origdate = {${origdate}}," >> $BIBFILE
                echo "url = {${texfile}}," >> $BIBFILE
                echo '}' >> $BIBFILE
        fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. A minimal example to go ahead is immensely helpful.

Comment: I would love to know more about your vacuum script , if you care to share. What I find useful, is when I write fast, sometimes I want to add an entry, while I am still on the page, rather than jumping to add to the .bib file. In this case an "append" type of flecontents, would be very useful.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I've added it. But I think possibly you didn't quite understand the OP's question. :-)

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks. I understood what the OP was asking, but was intrigued after reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

While `lua` is not required, `lua` does make it easy to put transfer information from tex to file. From what I understand, `filecontents` is a verbatim like environment and it is not easy to pass it variables from TeX. So, I came up with a minimal example of my own which I show below. Now that one can pass variables to lua, one can write as complex or simple a script that is needed in lua to get things going.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\title{New Article}
\author{New Author}

\RequirePackage{luatextra}

\begin{luacode}
  function writebib(author)
  bibtex_file = io.open("meta.bib", "w")
  bibtex_file:write("@techreport{alpha,title={Me},author={")
  bibtex_file:write(author)
  bibtex_file:write("}}")
  end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\makeatletter
\directlua{writebib("\luaescapestring{\@author}")}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need lua to write non-verbatim to a file. TeX has `\newwrite`, `\openout`, `\write` and `\closeout`. LaTeX3 provides additional i/o operations.

Comment: Yes, but processing entries and transferring them correctly would be quite a pain I think. I'm thinking about the need to replace the TeX version "First Author, Second Author" to the bib-friendly "First Author and Second Author". Quite natural to do it in lua than TeX.

Comment: In `\author{…}` you usually use `\and` to separate multiple authors. Expanding `\and` by `and` shouldn't be a real problem. Additionally, you should have a look into LaTeX3. There are several functions to replace tokens or strings, even using regular expressions.

Comment: Is there any specific reason I should prefer TeX and not use lua? It just seems lua is more elegant to write logic in.

Comment: No. If you like to use it, do it. But your premise, that using TeX would be complicated, because `filecontents` writes verbatim is wrong. You don't need `filecontents` to write with expansion or partial expansion to files. BTW: Neither your question nor your answer shows a need of modifications or similar.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the answer and patience. I'll look at the LaTeX3 functions to keep myself more informed.